# Dynamic allocation of a union of pointers - C

Tags: c, memory-management, unions

I am writing a basic library for low level image processing in C. I am aware that other (very good) libraries exist; this is a learning experience for me, not a means to an end.

I have defined the following (simplified, for this question) constructs:

```
union img_rawdata{
    uint8_t*  u8;
    uint16_t* u16;
    float*    flt;
};

enum img_type{
    IMG_U8,
    IMG_U16,
    IMG_FLT
};

struct image{
    union img_rawdata  rawdata;
    enum img_type      type;
    unsigned int       num_values;
};
```

My question is this: What is the favored way to dynamically allocate the proper pointer within the union?

Right now, the only way I see is to use a switch statement, like:

```
void alloc_img(struct image* img, enum img_type type, unsigned int num_vals){
    switch (type){
        case IMG_U8:
            img->rawdata.u8 = (uint8_t*)malloc(num_vals*sizeof(uint8_t));
        break;            
        case IMG_U16:
            img->rawdata.u16 = (uint16_t*)malloc(num_vals*sizeof(uint16_t));
        break;
        case IMG_FLT:
            img->rawdata.flt = (float*)malloc(num_vals*sizeof(float));
        break;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem so bad; however, in my implementation, the actual memory allocation is about 50 lines (as rawdata is not one dimensional, error checking, etc.).

Is there any preprocessor magic that can reduce code redundancy, or is this the best way to go about writing this?

Or, alternatively, is there a different way altogether to approach the problem that will avoid this issue entirely?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value from `malloc()`. Casting it is redundant; the cast may hide an error the compiler would have caught otherwise.

Comment: ... and due to what *pmg* states you do not need three different calls to `malloc()`.

Comment: Please see *pmg*'s answer.

Comment: Just saw it posted, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you aware that on some architectures pointers' size can differ depending on the type being pointed to? If you plan to be cross-platform this union img_rawdata may not be a good idea.

Comment: Why would the union not be a good idea? It's my understanding that, as long as the correct member union is used, you can successfully deference each of the pointers from the union regardless of size.

Comment: Hum, never mind, I thought you wanted to assign one member of the union and dereference using another member. Do you use the union instead of a struct only to save memory?

Comment: The union is to provide a generic image type that can hold different types. In regard to your original statement though, some of the answers below will be less portable than the solution shown above, as they rely on pointers being of like size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[assuming all types of pointers including `void *` have the same size]

Modify what you have like so

```
union img_rawdata {
  void * untyped;
  uint8_t * u8;
  uint16_t * u16;
  float * flt;
};

enum img_type {
  IMG_UNDEF = -1
  IMG_U8 = 0,
  IMG_U16,
  IMG_FLT,
  IMG_MAX
};
```

and add

```
const size_t img_type_size[IMG_MAX] = {
  sizeof(*((union img_rawdata *) NULL)->u8),
  sizeof(*((union img_rawdata *) NULL)->u16),
  sizeof(*((union img_rawdata *) NULL)->flt)
};
```

then replace the switch by:

```
assert(IMG_UNDEF < type && IMG_MAX > type);
img->rawdata.untyped = malloc(num_vals * img_type_size[type]);
```

Comment: `sizeof((union img_rawdata *) NULL)->u8)` is new syntax to me. Is there an advantage of that over `sizeof((union img_rawdata) NULL).u8)` ?

Comment: Okay, fair enough. as I said, I have never seen that before. You cannot cast NULL to a non-pointer type?

Comment: Yes, you cannot cast it to an aggregate type. @Glenn

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation. My last question; is there an inherent advantage structuring it like this instead of the `switch` proposed in another answer?

Comment: Less code, less possible mistakes. Also easy to maintain, as only type defintions and constants need to be added. @Glenn

Comment: Wait, won't `sizeof(((union img_rawdata *) NULL)->u8)` return the size of a `uint8_t *`, not the size of a `uint8_t`?

Comment: Indeed. Corrected. @Glenn

Answer (score 3):

```
void alloc_img(struct image * img, enum img_type type, unsigned int num_vals){
    size_t basesize = 0;
    switch (type){
        case IMG_U8:
            basesize = sizeof(uint8_t);
        break;            
        case IMG_U16:
            basesize = sizeof(uint16_t);
        break;
        case IMG_FLT:
            basesize = sizeof(float);
        break;
    }
    if (basesize) {
        img->rawdata.u8 = malloc(num_vals * basesize);
        // assigning to u8 is the same as assigning to any other member
        // but it may be better to use a void* as in
        // img->rawdata.voidptr = malloc(num_vals * basesize);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "default missing in switch\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd add a `default` branch to the `switch` logging/returning an error.